# is there some configuration or plugin to filter out all OPTIONS request from firefox network panel?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I just want to get rid of all these OPTIONS requests:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Firefox documentation you can use the filter box.

To get rid of all the `OPTIONS` requests you can use this query.

```
-method:OPTIONS
```

You can find out more by reading the documentation [here](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/network_monitor/request_list/).

Hope it helps.